# Why would I use input type date in a regular web application?

Tags: javascript, html, date, input, w3c

I am currently building an iOS App using Phonegap and jQuery Mobile, and I am using the HTML5 input type date element, for the user to enter their birthday. This makes total sense for a Phonegap app to use, because this invokes the phones native datepicker - thats great!

However, when using a desktop browser to test out my app (I am using Firefox 16), no datepicker is shown, obviously due to the fact that Firefox has not implemented this yet. Thats cool, except for the fact that I can enter whatever I want into that field - any format I want.

The specification says that it should use the `yyyy-mm-dd` format, and my iOS device does that. But, if I enter e.g `06-09-94`, that won't play nicely when I try to convert it to a JavaScript Date Object.

Here are my tests:

```
// Value is set to 1994-09-06
console.log(new Date($("input[type=date]")[0].value));
// > Date object representing September 6, 1994

// Value is set to 06-09-1994
console.log(new Date($("input[type=date]")[0].value));
// > Invalid date
```

I've read somewhere that internally (atleast for chrome), all "valid" date formats will be represented as `yyyy-mm-dd`, but that's not happening. http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome

> What kind of format does the input value return?
>
> The input.value always returns as yyyy-mm-dd regardless of the
>   presentation format.

So, as the title suggests: *Why would I want to use an `<input type="date">` in a non-mobile based web application?*

Comment: Because it makes it easier for your visitors to enter a valid date format. Correct me if I'm wrong, but in HTML 5, the date input element is not just a textfield, it's a DatePicker.

Comment: Yes, it is a datepicker when using a browser that implements it, which is not Firefox :)

Comment: The whole point of this question is that the visitor wont know the diference - he could enter anything into that field

Comment: `06-09-94` is not a date but nonsense (when looking at it critically). Is it supposed to be the 6th of September? The ninth of June? So not accepting that does make sense. Even worse: `06-07-09` - even more ambiguity.

Comment: Not if you live in Denmark. My Windows 7 clock in the tray says today is 30-10-2012

Comment: @Jeff Don't get me started on Firefox lol. I almost put a hole in my desk because of it last night ;-P

Comment: @JamesKent If it's not working in Firefox, you're doing something wrong ;);)

Comment: Actually, I'm not lol. I've had about 10 others tell me that there's nothing wrong with my code. And I've never had this problem before. Plus the problem only occurs in Firefox 15.0 not 14 and not 16.

Comment: @JamesKent I'm just kidding. ;)

Comment: LOL sorry I'm a bit high strung about it since its probably the most basic problem one could encounter :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to use the HTML 5 form elements because there is hope that one day all major browser support them. As you noticed, datepickers etc offer really great functionality out of the box, which would have to be coded by hand otherwise.

You wouldn't want to just let them stand on their own, though, in environments where you have no controller over what browser the user is using.

The suggested way to handle this at the moment is to check, if the browser supports the required form field, if not, use an alternative like a jQuery UI element.
Quickly googled tutorial: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/createelementcheck2.shtml

I think, some of the js framework handle such a check internally, at least for dojo I know that they try to use as much native browser functions as possible - but I'm not sure how it is handled with datepickers.

I have to say, I'm surprised firefox hasn't implemted this yet, Chrome and Opera seem to lead the way....

Comment: This is the answer I am looking for - confirmation that I should only use it when I know it's supported. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff *confirmation that I should only use it when I know it's supported* — that's not at all what I got from this answer. Furthermore, although Opera made some really dubious UI decisions when they first started implementing date inputs, all inputs whose type isn't supported will automatically fall back to text.

Answer (score 0):

Since not all browsers still support all HTML5 features you can't see all it's benefits right away.
The `<input type=date>` tag is one of those features, if you run the code in the Chrome browser it will open date picker, when you can choose the date by clicking on the arrow button. This feature is missing though on Safari browser. Just wait for updates of browsers.

Comment: So I shouldt use it for desktop browser web apps?

Comment: If you want to expand your compatibility with all browsers, you should avoid using it yet and use jQueryUI library.

Answer (score 0):

You check that the value is in an appropriate date format before trying to convert it to a `Date` object.

If it isn't, display an error message to the user instead (e.g. by adding a `<label>` by the `<input>` or using an `alert`).

Comment: Then I might as well use a JS datepicker - I just cant see the benefits or need for using it, if I was not building a phone app.

Comment: Because as time goes on, support will increase, and eventually you can drop the pollyfill and have a smaller codebase.